# OCMock failure mocking 'initWithAttributedString' on NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, ocmock, gh-unit

I'm trying to understand what is mockable and what isn't.

In an experiment with an NSMutableAttributedString, I don't appear to be able to mock `initWithAttributedString`.

```
- (void)test_mutableString_shouldWorkAsAMutableString {
    NSMutableAttributedString *_mutable = [OCMockObject mockForClass:NSMutableAttributedString.class];
    NSAttributedString *_string = [OCMockObject mockForClass:NSAttributedString.class];
    [[[(id)_mutable expect] andReturnValue:nil] initWithAttributedString:_string];
    [_mutable initWithAttributedString:_string];
}
```

This code won't run; for some reason the proxy for the mutable screen doesn't recognise the `initWithAttributedString` selector:

```
2013-03-12 11:25:30.725 UnitTests[11316:c07] TestItClass/test_4_mutableString_shouldWorkAsAMutableString ✘ 0.00s

    Name: NSInvalidArgumentException
    File: Unknown
    Line: Unknown
    Reason: *** -[NSProxy doesNotRecognizeSelector:initWithAttributedString:] called!

    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01c0602e __exceptionPreprocess + 206
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01948e7e objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01c05deb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   Foundation                          0x00862bcd -[NSProxy doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 75
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01bf5bbc ___forwarding___ + 588
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x01bf594e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    6   UnitTests                           0x00349e0b -[TestItClass test_4_mutableString_shouldWorkAsAMutableString] + 283
```

I am trying to understand how I can reliably use OCMock, but this confuses my and I'm not sure which OCMock calls I can expect to work and which I shouldn't.

I would very much appreciate some clarification on this, and an hints as to why the above doesn't work.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Why would you need to mock NSAttributedString?

Comment: David, I have some business logic that builds a NSAttributedString in a particular way. In order to test that logic, I need mock attributed strings to test the interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [learned something about Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110283/why-cant-i-get-my-category-instance-method-even-after-calling-it) trying to figure this one out.

Your basic problem is that the class of an object created by alloc'ing NSMutableAttributedString is not NSMutableAttributedString (always be wary of toll-free bridged classes). To get your code to work, try the following:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *realMutable = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
id mutable = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[realMutable class]];
id string = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[NSAttributedString class]];

[[[mutable expect] andReturn:@"YO" ] initWithAttributedString:string];
NSLog(@"MOCK: %@", [mutable initWithAttributedString:string]);

[mutable verify];

// Outputs 'MOCK: YO' and passes
```

Comment: Ah, I see. That's a nice way of hiding that wringle and still make the test code maintainable. Thanks!